# Insert a UIView between 2 other UIViews to create a list with 3 UIView's

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewanimation

I have in my application one `ViewController` that requires a `UIScrollView`

In this `UIScrollView` i have many `UIButton`'s. When i press one button bellow the button  that i touched i want to show a `UIView` animating his entrance. Just like a accordion, like this: [Jquery demo](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Currently i have this method to open the "accordion":

```
-(void) openView:(UIView *)view inFrame:(CGRect)final {
  CGRect frame = view.frame;
  frame.size.height = 0;
  frame.origin = finalFrame.origin;
  view.frame = frame;

  [self.buttonsView addSubview:view];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    view.frame = finalFrame;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished){
  }];
}
```

the `self.buttonsView` is the `UIView` that i use inside my `scrollview`.

With this method i can insert a view rigth after my button. But the problem is: I can't open the space between the buttons to enlarge my `buttonsView`

is there a way to do this?

```
button1
button2
button3
```

button 2 clicked:

```
button1
button2
a view
button3
```

button 2 clicked again:

```
button1
button2
button3
```

**And i can't use `UITableView`**

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `openView:inFrame:` method to also animate the frames of all the buttons below the one you tapped.

Comment: i was thinking on something like a layout mask, but i didn't find anything that could help me

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

//in .h file declare one variable

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btnpreviouslySelected;
CGRect customerButtonFrame,inventoryButtonFrame,templatesButtonFrame;
```

Consider btnCustomer,btnInventroy,btntemplate are your three buttons & assign them tag as 1,2,3 resp.
viewsearch is new view which you want to add in between two buttons

//in .m

```
//in view did load method set following 
btnpreviouslySelected=nil;
customerButtonFrame=btnCustomer.frame;
inventoryButtonFrame=btnInventory.frame;
templatesButtonFrame=btnTemplates.frame;


-(void) RepositioningFrameMneuTree
{
    btnCustomer.frame=customerButtonFrame;
    btnInventory.frame=inventoryButtonFrame;    
    btnTemplates.frame=templatesButtonFrame;    
}

-(void) RepositioningMenuTree:(int)iCaseValue
{
    if (iCaseValue==1) 
    {
        btnInventory.center=CGPointMake(btnInventory.center.x,btnInventory.center.y+300);

    }

    if (iCaseValue==2 || iCaseValue==1) 
    {
        btnTemplates.center=CGPointMake(btnTemplates.center.x,btnTemplates.center.y+300);

    }
}


-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)btn;
{       

        if(btnpreviouslySelected==btn)
        {

            //set to default location
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            //here remove search view
            [viwSearchView removeFromSuperview];

            [self RepositioningFrameMneuTree];           
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            return;
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];      


        //assign previousbutton to new button
        btnpreviouslySelected=btn;
            [self RepositioningFrameMneuTree]; 



            viwSearchView.frame=CGRectMake(0,btn.frame.origin.y+45,viwSearchView.frame.size.width,viwSearchView.frame.size.height);


            //add search view on your view
            [self.buttonsview addSubview:viwSearchView];


        //-------------------------------------------
        //change the location of button below selected button to show the search button
        switch (btn.tag) {

            case 1:

                [self RepositioningMenuTree:1];
                break;
            case 2:

                [self RepositioningMenuTree:2];
                break;
            case 3:
                //dont do any thing
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        //end animation
        [UIView commitAnimations];




}
```

Comment: the idea of tags on every button with the index of that button it is nice, but the same view can have 3 to 10 buttons, so having a IBOutlet to every button is not ok

Comment: But for changing the frame we required IBOUtlet for every buttons.Otherwise you have to try with taking the subviews in the scrollview & then adjust the frame according to tag of the buttons